# Why the previous input buffer is not stored in case of scanning of strings using scanf?

Tags: c

```
scanf("%d",&i);
scanf("%c",&ch);
```

In this case the newline(ie. the enter key pressed after the number)stays in the input buffer and carry forwards to the **ch**
But in this case :

```
scanf("%d",&i);
scanf("%s",s);
```

The input buffer doesn't contain the newline i.e. the buffer is cleared(i'm not sure if the buffer is cleared) and the newline is not taken in the string **s**

Can anyone throw some light on this? Why the newline is not taken in case of scanning the string?

Comment: This line: `scanf("%c",&ch);` should be: `scanf(" %c",&ch);`  Notice the leading space in the format string, because a space in a format string will consume any 'white space' encountered in stdin, at that location.  Careful reading of the man page for `scanf()` explains this action in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `%s` and `%c` is defined in the standard.

The `%s` specifier is defined as taking a sequence of non-whitespace characters, meaning that the initial whitespace (which includes `\n`) would be skipped:

> `%s` Matches a sequence of bytes that are not white-space characters. The application shall ensure that the corresponding argument is a pointer to the initial byte of an array of char, signed char, or unsigned char large enough to accept the sequence and a terminating null character code, which shall be added automatically. ([documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html))

`%c`, on the other hand, does not have any special treatment for whitespace:

> `%c` Matches a sequence of bytes of the number specified by the field width (1 if no field width is present in the conversion specification).

Comment: So how does `scanf` knows when to end taking input in case of `%s`? Is white space the "STOP" indicator for `scanf`? That means white spaces before the string doesn't matter but in the middle of string or at the end,it acts like "STOP" ,right?

Comment: @avistein Correct, whitespace is a stop indicator for `scanf` reading the data for the `%s` format specifier. It skips whitespace before reading the data, and ends reading as soon as whitespace is discovered following the input.